# Why I am getting Error 404 at Admin /Django

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I fix this error:
Page not found (404)
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

It's my urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('pages.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I want access to admin page

Comment: Please add traceback (error code) and which url you were trying to request

Comment: What is the `url` you have accessed?